MSAL with mgt-teamsfx-provider mgt components are no longer working
I've just updated to this packages:
` "@angular/animations": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.3",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^17.3.3",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.15",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.11.1",
    "@microsoft/mgt": "^4.2.1",
    "@microsoft/mgt-element": "^4.2.1",
    "@microsoft/mgt-teamsfx-provider": "^4.2.1",
    "@microsoft/teams-js": "^2.21.0",
    "@microsoft/teamsfx": "^2.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^7.0.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.1",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.12.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.4"`

The Sample posted here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/mgt-teamsfx-provider is also not working for me.
I am running an Angular 17 app inside Teams. Outside of Teams, I don't get any issues. The mgt components are loading fine. Inside of Teams, it is no longer working.
The error messages are:
Cannot get access token due to error: ErrorWithCode.UiRequiredError: Failed to get access token cache silently, please login first: you need login first before get access token.
My "auth-start.html" and "auth-end.html" are also a strict copy from the examples.
Auth-Start.html

 <!--This file is used during the Teams authentication flow to assist with retrieval of the access token.-->
<!--If you're not familiar with this, do not alter or remove this file from your project.-->

<html>

<head>
  <title>Login Start Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.21.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@azure/msal-browser@3.11.1/lib/msal-browser.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
      console.log("auth-start.html, microsoftTeams.app.initialize()");
      microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then(async (context) => {
        console.log("auth-start.html, microsoftTeams.app.getContext()");
        // Generate random state string and store it, so we can verify it in the callback
        var currentURL = new URL(window.location);
        console.log("auth-start.html, currentURL %s", currentURL);

        var clientId = currentURL.searchParams.get("clientId");
        console.log("auth-start.html, clientId %s", clientId);

        var scope = currentURL.searchParams.get("scope");
        console.log("auth-start.html, scope %s", scope);

        var loginHint = currentURL.searchParams.get("loginHint");
        console.log("auth-start.html, loginHint %s", loginHint);

        const msalConfig = {
          auth: {
            clientId: clientId,
            authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${context.user.tenant.id}`,
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
          },
          cache: {
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
          }
        }

        const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
        await msalInstance.initialize(); // new with 3.X
        console.log("auth-start.html, msalInstance initialized %O", msalInstance);

        //const msalInstance = await msal.PublicClientApplication.createPublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

        const scopesArray = scope.split(" ");
        const scopesRequest = {
          scopes: scopesArray,
          redirectUri: window.location.origin + `/auth-end.html?clientId=${clientId}`,
          loginHint: loginHint
        };
        console.log("auth-start.html, scopesRequest %O", scopesRequest);
        await msalInstance.loginRedirect(scopesRequest);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

Auth-End.html
<!--This file is used during the Teams authentication flow to assist with retrieval of the access token.-->
<!--If you're not familiar with this, do not alter or remove this file from your project.-->
<html>

<head>
  <title>Login End Page</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.21.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@azure/msal-browser@3.11.1/lib/msal-browser.min.js"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var currentURL = new URL(window.location);
    console.log("auth-end.html, currentURL %s", currentURL);

    var clientId = currentURL.searchParams.get("clientId");
    console.log("auth-end.html, clientId %s", clientId);

    microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
      console.log("auth-end.html, microsoftTeams.app.initialize()");
      microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then(async (context) => {
        console.log("auth-end.html, microsoftTeams.app.getContext()");
        const msalConfig = {
          auth: {
            clientId: clientId,
            authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${context.tid}`,
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false
          },
          cache: {
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
          }
        }

        //https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/acquire-token.md
        //https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/docs/v2-migration.md
        //https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/wiki/

        //const msalInstance = new window.msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);

        const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
        await msalInstance.initialize(); // new with 3.X
        console.log("auth-end.html, msalInstance initialized %O", msalInstance);
        
        msalInstance.handleRedirectPromise().then((tokenResponse) => {
          if (tokenResponse !== null) {
            console.log("auth-end.html, tokenResponse %O", tokenResponse);
            //alert(tokenResponse.accessToken);
            microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess(JSON.stringify({
              sessionStorage: sessionStorage
            }));
            //microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess();
            //sessionStorage.setItem(StorageKeys.accessToken, tokenResponse.accessToken);
          } else {
            microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure("Get empty response.");
          }
        }).catch((error) => {
          microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure(JSON.stringify(error));
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>

I've tried to find documentation for the latest version of MSAL (msal-browser), mgt-teamsfx-provider, mgt and mgt-element packages. It's been hours without any success at all. Any help is highly appreciated

Could you please let us know if this stopped working after updating the package?

I'm having this issue in React as well.

I can't figure out what is the actual cause for the error. New Teams, TeamsFxProvider, MSAL, .... It's so frustrating having to rework stuff that is already working every other month

Just to rule out the possibilities, could you please confirm if this stopped working after updating the package? Is it working with lower versions?

Tolga, do you trigger login first before render mgt components? If not, you can refer below code to add login logic:

Here is also a working sample you can refer using TeamsFx with mgt components: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/dev/graph-toolkit-contact-exporter.
In above sample, it uses "@microsoft/teamsfx": "2.3.0" with msal 2.x. If you want to use msal 3.x, you need to update the teamsfx to 2.3.1 and refer msal 3.x in your auth-start and auth-end page to make it work.
For your issue, if you already have login logic, you can downgrade the teamsfx to 2.3.0, and uses start, end page here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx-Samples/tree/dev/graph-toolkit-contact-exporter/public to try whether it works.
If it still not work, feel free to share related code, thanks~
